# Поправить перевод текста, отображающегося во время технических работ

Tags: дефект, локализация, технические-работы

Открыть страницы во время тех. работ:

1. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/login

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   Текст:

   > Войти в настоящее время недоступно
2. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/signup?ssrc=head

   > Signup в настоящее время недоступно

Для второй части есть строка: https://ru.traducir.win/string/6317

А в первую часть не понятно, что подставляется, т.к, к слову, `Signup` строка переведена в традусёре, но в тексте нет. Вероятно какой-то харкод.

Comment: А ещё на главной была фраза "Обычно, техническое обслуживание длиться менее часа." В ней однозначно лишний мягкий знак в слове "длится", и, скорее всего, не нужна запятая после "Обычно". Это в новый вопрос нужно? По метке `технические-работы` я кроме этого вопроса ничего не вижу

Comment: @EurobeatIntensifies можете задать отдельным вопросом )

Comment: Понял, сделаю. Спасибо!